# Different behavior using tab completion from executing `ls`

Tags: bash, ls, special-characters

I noticed this question on ServerFault:

> [FreeBSD: Directory called ^C (really!) - how to remove?](https://serverfault.com/questions/893343/freebsd-directory-called-c-really-how-to-remove)

I knew about the `^V` part long ago. What interests me in that post is that the OP can see the `^C` character as `^C`(caret followed by a `C`) in Tab completion, but not in `ls`. So I look up the man page a bit, and I can find `ls -b` which outputs `\003`, `ls -N` which does not do anything special to `^C`, and `ls --show-control-chars` which shows a Unicode character on the screen.

My first question is, is there a simple way for `ls` to generate the same type of output as Tab completion, namely `^C`(caret followed by a `C`)? (`cat -v` behavior).

My second question is, how does `$LANG` and the `$LC_*` environmental variables affect the output generated by Tab completion(I think it is documented in `complete` and maybe the Section 8 in Bash Manual but did not seem to find anything relevant)?

I am using `bash` 4.3 but solutions for other shells are also welcome.

Comment: I think you're getting confused by the difference between the nonprinting ASCII character Control-C (which is what's in the filename), and "^C", one of many printable *representations* of that character. Tab completion is going to produce the actual Control-C character, which the shell will *represent* as "^C" on the command line; but that's not what's actually there, it's a Control-C.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for your information. I think the shell is what translates it to `^C` (caret followed by a `C`) just as you said. I admit that I have ignored this.

Comment: The questioner does not appear confused to me.  Xe is asking why there is no configuration of `ls` (albeit that xe is using the wrong `ls` for the original question) that does the same thing with a filename containing a control character as the Bourne Again shell does.  There is no confusion here.  This is indeed the case.

Comment: @JdeBP What do you mean by "the wrong `ls`"? By the way I am male.

Comment: The original question was on FreeBSD, notice.  You aren't using FreeBSD `ls`.

Comment: @JdeBP I see. I noticed that but I don't have a FreeBSD system to test on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This behaviour is not the same across all shells.

The Bourne Again shell behaves as you describe, displaying the filename in a notation that does not match how such characters are input to the shell.  The TENEX C shell does the same.  In neither one does the two-character sequence `^C` match the one-character filename.

The Almquist and Korn shell just write the control character, which does nothing on many terminals, and include a width of 1, which is thus erroneous, in their column width calculations when displaying the completion list.  This throws column alignment off.

The Z shell is the only shell that does something that relates to command input usage.  Its menu-based tab completion displays the filename as `$'\003'`. That is exactly what one writes with (say) the `rm` command, and is exactly *what ZLE's tab completion will fill in for the `rm` command*, to remove the file with the Z shell:

```
rm $'\003'
```

## One can match the Korn and Almquist shells.

This is trivial.

The `-w` option simply causes the control character to be output as-is, which again does nothing on many terminals.  But at least `ls` has the nous to realize that it has a width of 0, and does not get the column alignment calculations wrong.

Yes, this is FreeBSD/TrueOS `ls`.

## And there is no configuration for `ls` to match the behaviour of the others.

Both `-B` and `-b` cause an unadorned octal escape sequence to be printed, there being no special C escape sequence for this character.  But no shell presents an *unadorned* octal escape sequence in the completion list.  The Z shell comes closest, but uses `$'…'` quoting around the octal escape sequence in its completions.

There is nothing at all that matches how the Bourne Again and TENEX C shells display the filename.

## Locales

Locales are largely irrelevant here.  This character is a non-printing control character pretty much irrespective of locale.  The C0 range (pace EBCDIC fans) is pretty much universally considered to be control characters.

Comment: Thank you for such an extensive answer, I have learnt a lot from it.